# Can I use MongoDB with Amazon EC2 small instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mongodb, amazon-ebs, scaling

I want to move my MongoDB from a virtual server to amazon web services. I know MongoDB provides a [preconfigured AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00CO7AVMY/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4), with three provisioned EBS volumes. But this is only available for m1.large instances and higher. But I need only small or medium instance and only standard EBS volumes. Do you know, if it is possible to start the AMI with my requirements? Or have I to build it on my self with standard EBS volumes? Instance upgrading is no problem, but can I also upgrade the standard EBS to provisioned IOPS if needed?

You may think, the small instance is not suitable for MongoDB, but currently our vserver has also only 1GB of memory and one cpu and it runs good for the current load of max 70 visits per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run MongoDB on a small or medium instance (I've often done this for testing purposes), but you cannot add pIOPS until you upgrade to larger sizes (m1.large is essentially the minimum), hence the preconfigured AMI is not available otherwise.

Therefore if you wish to deploy on the smaller instance sizes you will have to roll your own (so to speak), this is not particularly difficult - you can pick your preferred Linux image, and then [install MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) and follow the recommendations in the [Production Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) and you should be all set.

Some suggested reading to explain the choices behind the AMI and it's choice of sizing:

http://info.mongodb.com/rs/10gen/images/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf

Then, as well as that, some decent info on pIOPS:

http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/16/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/
http://www.stratalux.com/2012/08/09/putting-amazon%E2%80%99s-provisioned-iops-to-the-test/

Comment: Thanks. And how is it with upgrading a standard EBS volume to provisioned IOPS (while upgrading to a large)? Snapshot and create a new provisioned EBS volume from snapshot?